# Copy files and folders keeping windows 7 interface

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, process, xcopy

I have done with xcopy to copy files from one folder to another:

```
Process proc = new Process();
//proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe";
string arg = @"R:\TREM " + fbd.SelectedPath + " /E /I /Y";
//proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\source C:\destination /E /I /Y";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
proc.Start();
```

Now I want to see the exact small window(on copy time) when we copy anything using windows 7 interface, like `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+V`. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [IFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771.aspx) interface of [Shell interfaces.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Example -> [IFileOperation in Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx)